# csv xls export to excel using respond_to spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, xls

I want to export results generated from my rails app to excel format.  distribution_sheet, results and specimens are all models.  This is my script in my controller:

```
    def first

  @distribution_sheet = DistributionSheet.find(:all, :conditions => ["lifecycle_state = ?","closed"]).last

  @results = @distribution_sheet.results

  @specimens = @distribution_sheet.specimens

 end

  include DisplayResultHelper
    def show
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
        format.csv {
          @specimens.each do |sp|
         send_data(generate_csv([["Lab No","Assay","Batch","Cuttoff"],[sp.id]]),
 :filename => "my_data-#{Time.now.to_date.to_s}.csv",
         :type => 'text/csv')
          end
                   }
         format.xls{
         send_data(generate_xls([["Lab No","Assay","Batch","Cuttoff"],[]]),
         :filename => 'my_date.xls',
         :type => 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
             }

      end
    end
  end
```

This works if I add any words inside the arrays, but once I add sp.id it fails. I want to add the data in sp.id.  Any clues?

Mark

Comment: Did you write `generate_xls` and `generate_csv`? Or do they come from a library? Either show us the source from those functions or say which library it comes from. Now it is very hard for us to know what those functions expect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which library you're using - but perhaps it requires real strings in those arrays, so try passing in `sp.id.to_s` instead of just `sp.id`